# Количество символов в выводе для целого числа

Tags: c#

Как вывести число так, чтобы оно занимало определенное количество символов?
Пример:
Есть числа 321 и 34, нужно чтобы они занимали 5 символов.
То есть "__321" и "___34" соответственно (земля = пробел)

Comment: А для чего вам такой вывод и в чём суть программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
int i = 123;
Console.WriteLine("{0,5}", i);
```

Где в строке формата: `5` - общая длина выводимого числа.

Answer (score 3):

Можно через спецификатор ширины формата.

Вот такой код:

```
int n = 5;
string s = string.Format("|{0}| |{1,10}|", n, n);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

выдаёт:

```
|5| |         5|
```

---

Если вы не используете `string.Format` или другие аналогичные функции, можно воспользоваться `PadLeft`:

```
s = n.ToString().PadLeft(10);
```